# Deploy Vosao in eclipse in windows

Tags: windows, eclipse, google-app-engine, content-management-system, vosao

I am using google app engine in eclipse in windows OS. I want to used Vosao CMS(which is develop for GAE). But i can't deploy in eclipse in windows and easily deploy in eclipse in windows.So how vosao(content management system) deploy in eclipse in windows OS.

Comment: who are thinking that this is not a useful question. Please give me the resion. This is a link to deploy vosao in ubantu http://www.rarejava.com/blog/2011/07/deploying-vosao-from-eclipse so please tell me how deploy vosao in windows in above way.Than give the vote of my question that it is not a useful one.

Comment: If you want to learn how to deploy eclipse on Windows, research that, and ask if you need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not direct way to deploy the Vosao in eclipse in windows. But there is a alternate solution.

For- Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

1.Unzip the war file.

2.than create a project in eclipse.

3.Than copy the contain of unzip folder one by one & paste in proper position in your project.like servlet paste in src & jsp pages paste in war folder.

4.care fully read this point
In unzip folder there is a web-inf folder & also in your project there is web-inf folder. So copy the contain of web-inf folder carefully in project web-inf folder.

For-Eclipse IDE for Java EE developers

File-->Import-->web-->war

It may be work. In my project both are work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good tutorial on this.
http://www.rarejava.com/blog/2011/07/deploying-vosao-from-eclipse

I had do minor modifications on my side for Maven and Subclipe 1.8. Other than that the Blog worked like a charm

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, as the OP's problem is that they can't get eclipse running in the first place.